# Is it possible to find and bind to a random unused IP address in the private block 127.0.0.0/8?

Tags: ip, localhost, ip-address, loopback-address

The alternative is to use a daemon to manage and hand out those IP addresses. Trying to get DHCP daemon software to serve out IP addresses in 127.0.0.0/8 is weird and doesn't seem to work well for me and the alternative is to write my own DHCP like daemon (but for localhost.) Also, a daemon has troubles with staleness unlike with the OS which knows when applications unexpectedly exit.

Also, I can't use the trick of `connect`ing to a broadcast address to auto-bind to an address because that doesn't allow me to select the port.

Answer (score -2):

The 127.0.0.0/8 block is not able to be used outside the host on which it is configured.  It is not a "Private" block, and most DHCP servers are smart enough to not assign addresses from this block.  The addresses in this range are of no use other than for the host to talk to itself.

Comment: That IP addresses in 127.0.0.0/8 are not handable out on public networks is exactly the reason I want to use IP addresses there because those addresses are guaranteed to be local to the host and I am handing those addresses out to various processes on one computer. Using these addresses for the host to talk to itself is exactly the use I intend them for.

Comment: You can' t hand it outside the local host. These addresses cannot be used on a LAN, only within the host itself. They are not private addresses like `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, or `192.168.0.0/16` which can be used on a LAN. It doesn't matter if all your hosts have the address `127.0.0.1` (the default) since no host can ever see any address in that range on another host.

Comment: The "hosts" are processes on the same computer. Of course, they can see one another.

Comment: Then you are confused how this works. A host, meaning a physical PC or VM, only needs one loopback address. The loopback address goes on the interface which just sends the traffic back to the sender. It doesn't ever go out the interface and DHCP can't deal with it. Each VM would have its own virtual interface, but none of the other VMs can see its loopback address. You can't for instance, send anything from `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.2`. The address just hairpins the traffic.

Comment: I don't follow. Look. I have set up a DNS server on my computer that hands out various different IP addresses for different names under the `localhost` zone. I could map all the names to `127.0.0.1` but I want to be able to use the same port for different services so I need different addresses. Basically, I need both `http://myservicea.localhost:80` and `http://myserviceb.localhost:80` to work. For this reason, I need multiple loopback addresses and I need to hand them out via a service similar to DHCP.

Comment: The IP address (layer-3) has nothing to do with the port (layer-4), so you can use the differnet port numbers on the same IP address.  This is done all the time, with HTTP (80), HTTPS (443), DNS (53), etc. on the same IP address. You can send packets to an HTTP server out 127.0.0.1 at the random port selected for sending, and you receive it back on 127.0.0.1:80 which the HTTP server is listening on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90938/discussion-between-steven-stewart-gallus-and-ron-maupin).

Comment: RFC 5735, Special Use IPv4 Addresses, Section 3, Global and Other Specialized Address Blocks for the 127.0.0.0/8 block: tools.ietf.org/html/…, "A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host. This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback. As described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere."